# example of stardog sparql insert query in java

Tags: java, sparql, stardog

Can somebody give one java example of sparql insert/Delete query in Stardog.

there is only `queryExecution.execSelect()` method available. 
there is no `queryExecution.execInsert()` or `queryExecution.execDelete()`  available.
Please give one working example.

**EDIT**

I've found this this from stardog docs page.

http://stardog.com/docs/#notes

**As of 1.1.5, Stardog's SPARQL 1.1 support does not include: UPDATE query language**

does that means no way out for editing a tuple once entered?

Comment: This can be of help : http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201209.mbox/%3COFAB6B5A21.2EBF2448-ONC1257A7E.007AEBC5-C1257A7E.007BB147@netage.nl%3E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below one is a sample program of inserting a graph and removing it.

```
package com.query;

import java.util.List;

import org.openrdf.model.Graph;
import org.openrdf.model.Statement;
import org.openrdf.model.URI;
import org.openrdf.model.impl.GraphImpl;
import org.openrdf.model.impl.ValueFactoryImpl;
import org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException;

import com.clarkparsia.stardog.StardogDBMS;
import com.clarkparsia.stardog.StardogException;
import com.clarkparsia.stardog.api.Connection;
import com.clarkparsia.stardog.api.ConnectionConfiguration;
import com.clarkparsia.stardog.jena.SDJenaFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws StardogException, QueryEvaluationException {
    String appDbName ="memDb";
    String selectQuery="SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o WHERE { ?s ?p  ?o }";
    StardogDBMS dbms = StardogDBMS.toServer("snarl://localhost:5820/")
            .credentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()).login();
    List<String> dbList = (List<String>) dbms.list();
    if (dbList.contains(appDbName)) {
        System.out.println("droping " + appDbName);
        dbms.drop(appDbName);
    }
    dbms.createMemory(appDbName);
    dbms.logout();
    Connection aConn = ConnectionConfiguration
            .to("memDb")    // the name of the db to connect to
            .credentials("admin", "admin") // credentials to use while connecting
            .url("snarl://localhost:5820/")
            .connect(); 
    Model aModel = SDJenaFactory.createModel(aConn);
    System.out.println("################ GRAPH IS EMPTY B4 SUBMITTING ="+aModel.getGraph()+ "################");

    URI order = ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance().createURI("RDF:president1");
    URI givenName = ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance().createURI("RDF:lincoln");
    URI predicate = ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance().createURI("RDF:GivenNane");


    Statement aStmt = ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance().createStatement(order,predicate,givenName);
    Graph aGraph = new GraphImpl();
    aGraph.add(aStmt);
    insert(aConn, aGraph);


    ParameterizedSparqlString paraQuery = new ParameterizedSparqlString(selectQuery);
    QueryExecution qExecution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(paraQuery.asQuery(),aModel);
    ResultSet queryResult = qExecution.execSelect();
    System.out.println("############### 1 TUPPLE CAME AFTER INSERT ################");
    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, queryResult);

    aGraph.add(aStmt);
    remove(aConn, aGraph);


    paraQuery = new ParameterizedSparqlString(selectQuery);
    qExecution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(paraQuery.asQuery(),aModel);
    queryResult = qExecution.execSelect();
    System.out.println("################ DB AGAIN EMPTY AFTER REMOVE ################");
    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, queryResult);


    System.out.println("closing connection and model");
    aModel.close();
    aConn.close();  
}
private static void insert(final Connection theConn, final Graph theGraph) throws StardogException {
    theConn.begin();
    theConn.add().graph(theGraph);
    theConn.commit();
}

private static void remove(final Connection theConn, final Graph theGraph) throws StardogException {
    theConn.begin();
    theConn.remove().graph(theGraph);
    theConn.commit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stardog does not yet support SPARQL update, but as was pointed out to you on the mailing list, there are 5 ways you can modify the data once it's loaded.  You can use our HTTP protocol directly, any of the 3 Java API's we support, or you can use the command line interface.

Comment: It will be really helpful if you can provide an example of Java API way to modify data once it is loaded.

Comment: Examples for using every single API Stardog supports are provided *in* the distribution.  Further, there is rather extensive documentation on the website which shows code examples.

Comment: Per @Michael's comment - see Programming with Java (http://stardog.com/docs/java/) to get started or see the examples in the Stardog distribution

Comment: For reference here is the mailing list thread referenced - https://groups.google.com/a/clarkparsia.com/forum/#!topic/stardog/nNklIn37O2A

Comment: thank you all.. got a sample code from sample programs in the distribution. 
Modified it and made it a simple example. please find the next answer.

Comment: @Michael Unfortunately, it needs to be updated in some other places, too.  I found this question through [Stardog data loading and Jena](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24332922/1281433), and that got me looking through the documentation, and I think I found that old link in there somewhere too (but I can't find it at the moment, unfortunately).

Comment: Just an update - Stardog does support SPARQL Update now - http://docs.stardog.com/#_sparql_update